# The Security of AES-N-GCM

Tags: aes, gcm, aes-gcm

In the paper [The Security and Performance of the GaloisCounter Mode(GCM) of Operation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1.4591&rep=rep1&type=pdf),it shows the AES GCM SECURITY in Corollary 1.

> there are no distinguishing attacks against AES-N-GCM that work with distinguishing advantage greater than $A_{A E S-N}+q^{2} 2^{-116}-q 2^{-89.4}$

> there are no forgery attacks against AES-N-GCM that work with forgery advantage greater than$A_{A E S-N}+q^{2} 2^{-116}-q 2^{-89.4}-q 2^{-128}$

But I can not get the same result (the right corollary) from the theorem 1 & 2 as the paper described when I plug in the value of parameters.
Here are the Theorem 1 & 2:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I presented my calculating process below.

$A_{E} \geq A_{G C M}-q^{2} 2^{-129}\left(94^{2}+2 \times 2 \times 95\right)-q \times 95 \times 2^{-96}$
$A_{E} \geq A_{G C M}-q^{2} \times 9216 \times 2^{-129}-q \times 95 \times 2^{-96}$
$A_{E} \geq A_{G C M}-q^{2} 3^{2} \times 2^{-119}-q \times 2^{-89.4}$

I notice that my result has a  $-q^{2} 3^{2} \times 2^{-119}$  item.However,the corollary in paper displays a $+q^{2} 2^{-116}$ .

Comment: Corollary 1 just plugs in some concrete values into the formulae of theorems 1 and 2.  What are you confused about?  Did you get a different formulae when you inserted the values (128 bit block size, 1500 byte plaintexts)?

Comment: @poncho  Thanks for quick response, I have no idea why I just got the email message ...And yes,I plug in values ( w=128 , l(lv)=96 , t = 96 ,l =12000 ) and it doesn' t equal the Corollay 1. Could you please give a full calculation process about that? maybe I don't understand the paper well enough, your answer could be of great help.Thanks.

Comment: @poncho I have no idea how to get the corollay 1 .So please help me if i's convenient.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've not rewarded the bounty yet as the difference between $2^{-119}$ and $2^{-116}$ isn't explained, although a factor of $2^3 = 8$ difference seems rather minimal in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have computed things correctly. However, you have quoted their Corollary 1 wrong: you've included an extra $-q^22^{-128}$ term in the confidentiality part  (don't know if that was what confused you though). To get their $2^{-89.4}$ instead of your $2^{-89.5}$ simply include more decimals of $\log_2(95)$.

Comment: It seems that there is indeed an "extra" term , but it just followed the process of pluging in the conceret values.I update my quesion so that you may understand why the term displays.@hakoja